# AJAX: sending xmlhttp request in PHP loop but result is not dynamic

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a table that is given based on the option selected in a . This table generates list of students based on class selected. I want a dynamic modals popup each time the SMS button on a student row is clicked it is suppose to show the related parent's name dynamically. It's actually doing this but the issue is it is not dynamic one i refresh the page the data for the first student button clicked is what shows as response for every other one. until i refresh again. I select another and it shows thesame for every other student
Though when i used develop tool(network) in browser the xmlrequest was sent sucessfully and the interesting thing is the passed "id" param for the selected student is correct. but it just showing the same one that's selected first in the modal popup after refresh

the code looks like this
`

```
  function smsmodal(id){
     var data= {"id" : id};
     jQuery.ajax({
         url : '/sms/include/smsmodal.php',
         method : "post",
         data : data,
         success: function(data){
             jQuery('body').append(data);
             jQuery('#sms-modal').modal('toggle');
         },
         error: function(){
             alert("Something went wrong")
         }
     });
 }
```

` 
And for the loop:

```
<?php
require_once '../../service/mysqlcon.php';
$parentID = $_POST['parentID'];
$selected = sanitize($_POST['selected']);
$studentquery = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM students WHERE class = '$parentID' ORDER BY lastname");
$count = mysqli_num_rows($studentquery);
$i = 1;
ob_start(); ?>
<?php 
if($count < 1){
    ?>
    <br><br>
    <h4 class="text-warning text-center bg-warning" style="padding:20px">No student has been registered in this class.</h4>
    <?php
}else{
?> ...... other html..
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead><th><input type="checkbox"> Roll</th><th>Photo</th><th>Student Name</th><th>Address</th><th>Actions</th></thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php while($s = mysqli_fetch_assoc($studentquery)) :?>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox"> <?=$i;?></td>
                <td> <img src="<?=$s['photo'];?>" alt="photo" class="img-responsive" id="photo"></td>
                <td><?php echo $s['lastname'].' '.$s['firstname'];?></td>
                <td><?=$s['address'];?></td>
                <td><button class="btn btn-success btn-xs" type="button" onclick="smsmodal(<?=$s['id']; ?>)" style="width:80px"><span class="fa fa-mobile"></span> SMS</button> </td>
            </tr>
           <?php $i++;?>
         <?php endwhile; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</div>
<?php } ?>
<?php echo ob_get_clean(); ?>
```

Comment: There is no attachment for the code. Please update the question

Comment: Clear your cache from network tab and  unchecked preseve log

Comment: _"the code looks like this"_ - That's your issue, you have none :-o

Comment: Please check again. Thanks

Comment: I have added the code. i cleared cache and unchecked preserve log. its still the same.